# Console appears when I open my programmatically compiled program

Tags: c#, compilation

I have a program, that compiles an app. The app it creates is supposed to be hidden within the background or just not visible.

This is what I have for the app that's suppose to be in the bg:

```
this.ShowIcon = false;
this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
this.Visible = false;
this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal;
```

After it's created by my program, I open it and for some reason. There's a command prompt that opens and the form is clearly visible.

Also, it works fine if I create an empty project and put the source in there and run it

Any ideas what might be causing it?

Comment: We need to know more information; how are you compiling the program that's being run?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear *how* you're compiling, but you want at least the equivalent of:

```
csc /target:winexe [rest of command line as before]
```

Basically the default "project type" from the command line is equivalent to "console application".

If that doesn't help, please give a *lot* more information.